# movl with left operand with 3 sub-operands?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

This is some partial code , after a call to a function .

```
movl   12(%ebp),%ecx  
movl   8(%ebp),%esi    
movl   (%esi,%ebx,4),%edx
```

This is the corresponds C function :

```
void  foo(MyType_t A[], int n);
```

So basically , `%esi` is `A[]`  , and `%ecx` is `n`

What does the 3rd line means ? please note that the left operand has 3 sub-operands .

```
%edx = A[4 * %ebx + %esi] ?
```

Regards

Comment: @chikuba: For the current exercise the size of myType does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
movl   (%esi,%ebx,4),%edx
```

is AT&T syntax for "scale, index, base" (SIB) addressing.  `%esi` is the base address, `%ebx` is the index, and 4 is the "scale" (the multiplier applied to the index to generate a byte offset to the base address).

(The equivalent Intel syntax equivalent is more explicit: `mov edx, dword ptr [esi+ebx*4]`.)

```
%edx = A[4 * %ebx + %esi] ?
```

Probably not, because the effective address calculation in this addressing mode works in units of bytes, whereas C array indexing works in units of the size of an array element.

If `%esi` is the base address of `A` in memory, and `%ebx` is `n`, and the size of a single element of `A` (i.e. `sizeof(MyType_t)`) is 4, then `%esi + %ebx * 4` gives the address of `A[n]`; so the instruction would mean `%edx = A[n]` in that case.